# Is it possible to measure memory [RAM+SWAP] a R calculation utilizes?

Tags: r, linux, memory, ram

I have the following problem:

I am doing a rather resource heavy calculation with R using the:

```
library(fDMA)
```

and the command:

```
grid.dma(y= dmLOGRET2,x=dmlDRIVERS2,grid.alpha=gra,grid.lambda=grl,initvar=4400000,parallel=TRUE)
```

And if I use all my variables my computer can't finish the task in 50 hours after that I had 20gb of ram allocated and 90gb of swap allocated by R.
(I had to limit the RAM usage to 20gb so my computer would run somewhat smoothly)
My plan was to recompile R with the --enable-memory-profiling option enabled and then use:

```
profmem({grid.dma(...)})
```

but it just shows me the memory consumption of the finished calculation not the maximum memory used in the process of calculating it.

I wanted to make an assumption of how much RAM i would have to rent, letting the calculation run through a loop from two to a "doable" amount of variables and then extrapolating to the total amount of variables I have. Measuring the amount of RAM the instances of R consume (it spawns total amount of threads -1 instances of R).
The only way I see now is to sit in-front of the pc for days and taking note by hand, and that is not something I want to do.

So the question is, is there anyway I can track the amount of RAM and swap used by the R instances spawned by the command ?

Comment: What's the actual output of `profmem`?  Have you tried using `gctorture()`? (if you do, be prepared for it to run VERY slowly. Look at the help file first.